# Identify set for trans-orange assembly

Tags: set-identification

[image]

I am sorting through my son’s old Lego sets and don’t know which this belongs to. The orange polygon pieces are similar to some Nexo Knights sets.

Answer (score 5):

This is the tail end section of [70674-1 Fire-Fang](https://brickset.com/sets/70674-1/Fire-Fang).

[image]

Found by searching for [sets containing](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4264952) "Plate 2X4 cross-coupling".

Answer (score 1):

<s>There are only [10 sets containing that piece in trans-orange](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6120910), and none of them resemble your assembly. This must be the result of some free play using parts from several sets.</s>

Comment: TIL there are two versions of "Roof rock tile 4X4 W. angle":  [6120910 made in 2016](https://brickset.com/parts/6120910/roof-rock-tile-4x4-w-angle) and [an updated mould, 6174064 used between 2019 and 2020](https://brickset.com/parts/6174064/roof-rock-tile-4x4-w-angle)

Comment: There had to be a good reason that Ivan would have missed this.  I love this attention to detail.  Bravo, bravo.

Comment: I didn't look hard enough, and I just assumed there was only such a trans-orange part. My apologies.

Comment: I would have assumed the same. But the overall quality of the sub-assembly (neatly arranged dishes, arches, ...) was more like that of an official model instead of a kid's MOC, so I tried to find the set onto which the orange parts were grafted as "aftermarket" upgrades - and that's how I discovered this.